# api get request, handle 404

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, http-status-code-404

I am looking into handling 404 requests from api call where I am returning html when it occours.

```
$http.get('/api/house/' + $routeParams.id)
   .then(function (res) {

    $scope.houses = res.data;

}, function (err) {

    //when not found I am binding html from response
    if(err.status == 404){  
        $scope.errHtml = $sce.trustAsHtml(err.data);
    }

});
```

returned html for 404:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>

   <meta charset="utf-8">
   <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
   <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/resources/css/bootstrap.min.css">

   <title>404</title>

</head>
<body>

    <div>test 404</div>

</body>
</html>
```

in view I have:

```
<div ng-bind-html="errHtml"></div>
```

I am trying to understand if this is the best way to handle 404 from api call in angular js

Comment: you dont like "<!doctype html><html><head>" again in your page.  better way to create a state and then in error function use state.go("pageNotFound");

Comment: is that UI router specific as I dont have it?

Comment: what technique you are using for routing?

Comment: angular $routeProvider

Comment: you can use $location.url('/error')

Comment: I know I could but I dont think that's the right way as it will relocate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way to handle error responses in angularjs is to write an `$http interceptor`. Just write an interceptor service and push it to `$httpProvider` interceptors and then you can handle all your errors at one place. 
See the Documentation [here](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http)
The code will look like

```
.factory('httpRequestInterceptor', function ($q, $location) {
    return {
        'responseError': function(rejection) {
            if(rejection.status === 404){
                $location.path('/404/');                    
             }
            return $q.reject(rejection);
         }
     };
});
```

Then, you can inject this service into `interceptor` in config block

```
.config( function ($httpProvider) {
    $httpProvider.interceptors.push('httpRequestInterceptor');
});
```

You can handle other error codes also here and redirect accordingly. Hope this will help.

Comment: this will also relocate to /404 and wont keep the route

Comment: You can have a route `.when("/404", { templateUrl : "404.html" })` and direct the user there with `$location.path('/404'); or if you want to show some error  alerts, you can do the same here without redirecting to 404@user1751287

Comment: I do have it but I also have backend 404 handler hence after intercept route becomes http://websites.com/404

Comment: So, once the error occurs, what do you want to show? @user1751287

Comment: I would like to keep the route and show 404 template

Comment: you are using `ui-router` or `ng-route?`

Comment: dont have ui-router

Comment: I don't think there is standard way with `ng-route` to achieve this.

Comment: anything I could do, perhaps with $route.current.templateUrl;

Comment: One solution I can suggest is to have a `ng-include` of error template with `ng-if` in your app's index and an `ng-if` in you `ng-view`.  Once an error comes, change the flag accordingly. Not sure whether it'll work perfectly and not a recommended solution for best code.